The format in the last cell of a column in a table keeps losing it format

I have a formula in the 5th column which is:
=XLOOKUP(1,([@Data]=PlanTable[Data])*([@Utilaj]=PlanTable[Utilaj]),PlanTable[Plan])/COUNTIFS([Data],[@Data],[Utilaj],[@Utilaj])

I've tried selecting the whole column and change the format, it didn't work, it continuously converts it to "dd-mmm-yy".

I have created a similar sheet like yours: at the beginning it looks like this:

As far as the format is concerned, I have set the format of the cell with the number 100 to numeric, 0 decimals:

I click on my cell (the one containing 100), and press CtrlSPACE (for selecting the entire column), right-click, format cells, and apply the same format.
This is the result:

Have fun!
